# Is there any way to activate/run osgi Bundle form another running bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am looking for a possibility to activate a OSGi Bundle form another running bundle, is it possible ?

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve with activating the other bundle? Maybe there is a completely different solution.

Comment: I have an application with multiple OSGi bundles, on a specific event/external trigger I have to run some other bundle. my OSGi project(Powermatcher) has web interface to activate bunldes.  But I am looking for a way to control with other bundle.

Comment: In that case the proposal form Peter sounds like the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the concept of a *management agent* in the specification. You will need a Bundle Context object. There are several ways of getting this context:

- Highly Recommended: Using DS, you can declare a BundleContext object as parameter in the activate method
- Not perfectly safe: Use FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Class).getBundleContext()
- Only use when DS is not an option: Use an activator, a BundleContext object is passed

The BundleContext has a method `Bundle installBundle(String)`. You can pass a URL to the JAR file that holds the bundle. To start the bundle you can all `start` on it.

Since you're likely not well versed in OSGi you might want to take a look at Apache Felix FileInstall. This allows you to drop bundles in a directory that are then automatically installed. Though the API is simple, managing an OSGi framework has a lot of complicated cases due to the interaction with the rest of the world.

Comment: thanks for the response, In my bundle there are couple of Components with Activate method, how can I start/Activate those components?

Comment: If you use OSGi enRoute setup (bndtools) then they are started automatically

Comment: Looks like component has some dependency here is my component description:     @Component(designateFactory = Auctioneer.Config.class,
           immediate = true,
           provide = { ObservableAgent.class, MatcherEndpoint.class })

Comment: I have tried to use @Component(immediate=true) but not worked

Comment: You're using the old bnd annotations and you do not provide any context information of your setup, which makes it hard to help. I can help you if you have the same problem using OSGi enRoute (http://enroute.osgi.org, try the Quick start). Alternatively you can provide a workspace on Github